# NSMutableArray sort - error message

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray

I have a `NSMutableArray` generated by `XMLParser`, I would like to sort the table by category and delete the duplicates `abbcbc = abc`. Everything works, but when I click on the last entry generated by the `XMLParser`(here c), in the first table i can read it, but in the sort table i've the following error :

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<item 0x68a7e20> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is
 not key value coding-compliant for the key rss.'
 *** First throw call stack: (0x1849052 0x1cdcd0a 0x1848f11 0xd02032 0xc73f7b 0xc73eeb 0xc82b 0xd32a35 0x308f6 0x3cab0 0xd3102d 0xb94a
 0x38571d 0x385952 0xc7a86d 0x181d966 0x181d407 0x17807c0 0x177fdb4
 0x177fccb 0x2173879 0x217393e 0x2f5a9b 0x287d 0x27f5) terminate called
 throwing an exceptionsharedlibrary apply-load-rules all (gdb)
```

if you need the code,  it is [here](http://www.recontv.fr/02_novembre.zip) and the XML is [here](http://www.recontv.fr/testXml.xml).

PS : you need to put the link in the application to read to XML, and you must enter want you want for Login/Password (i'll make it soon) thank again

EDIT : I delete the folder with my code since the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[<item 0x68a7e20> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key rss
```

Have you tried looking into the item.h file? Look if you have synthesized the "rss" property.

Comment: thank you so much ^^ i wasn't synthesized the 'rss' property and now it's fixed !! But why the error wasn't come earlier ??